# Sorting both rows and columns of pivot table

Tags: c#, pivot-table, nreco

Trying to have pivot table output with sorted rows and columns

I've tried different combinations of `sortrowkey`, `col` keys etc and can't find the right syntax. Latest try was making sure the data doing into the cube before the pivot was sorted and using the `preservegrouporder`.

```
var pvtTbl = new PivotTable(
    new[] { "YearQuarterMonth" },
    new[] { "StageName" },
    slicedCube);
_ = pvtTbl.PreserveGroupOrder == true;
pvtTbl.SortRowKeysByColumnKey(null, 1, ListSortDirection.Ascending);
_ = pvtTbl.PreserveGroupOrder == true;
pvtTbl.SortColumnKeysByRowKey(null, 1, ListSortDirection.Ascending);
//pvtTbl.SortRowKeys(null, 1, ListSortDirection.Ascending);
//pvtTbl.SortColumnKeys(null, 1, ListSortDirection.Ascending);
var strJsonWr = new StringWriter();
var jsonWr = new PivotTableJsonWriter(strJsonWr);
```

So far it seems to only apply `1` or none of the sorts, never both.

Answer (score 0):

First of all please note that when you set `PreserveGroupOrder=true` pivot table rows/columns are ALWAYS ordered by labels, even if you call `SortRowKeysByColumnKey` or `SortColumnKeysByRowKey` to order by *values*, this sort is applied only to rows/columns *inside* groups. In your case you have only one dimension per axis, and this option doesn't change anything.

Let's see what happens next:

```
pvtTbl.SortRowKeysByColumnKey(null, 1, ListSortDirection.Ascending);
```

here you sorted *rows* by row totals values (as column key that identifies a column with values to sort is null), and measure index is 1 (which means 2nd measure). Important: this means that your `slicedCube` should have at least 2 measures defined with CompositeAggregatorFactory.

Then you call:

```
pvtTbl.SortColumnKeysByRowKey(null, 1, ListSortDirection.Ascending);
```

which now sorts *columns* by column total values (again, by 2-nd measure). Sequence of calls is important, as sort by values for columns may depend on previous sort on rows.

Hope this explanation helps.